# FixedPanel in SplitContainer causes ignorance of size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm having the following code to set the width of the first panel to the width I need (for some reason I need to divide the expectedWith by two to get the actual width to be my expectedWith - don't know why).

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = expectedWith / 2;
```

The next thing I need is that the first panel is fixed, means that if you resize the window, only the second panel gets larger and the first stays in size. To achieve this I use the following line:

```
splitContainer1.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel1;
```

Problem now: it seems that the FixedPanel-property completly ignores the size of the first panel. It doesn't matter which value I set the SplitterDistance-property to if I used the FixedPanel-line. It is always the same. It doesn't even matter if I set SplitterDistance in the form designer.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: It is impossible to do this. I'm getting a NotSupportedException where it says that I should use SplitterDistance instead.

Comment: I've just tried this and I don't see a problem.. no matter in what order I set / unset different properties, everything seems to work fine. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Wow, you're right. The problem only occurs if the content of Panel1 is using .Dock = DockStyle.Fill. Crazy stuff... I'm looking forward how to solve it.

Comment: Found out. Setting the Dock-property right after setting the FixedPanel works.

Comment: For some reason, setting the Dock property of the child control after setting FixedPanel also worked for me. Although, it took a rebuild of the controls before it would behave. This is quite odd. You'd think something as trivial as setting a distance property wouldn't be so troublesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can answer my own question. This only happens if the content of the appropriate panel is using DockStyle.Fill in its Dock-property. The solution is to set the DockStyle.Fill value right after setting FixedPanel. This was also responsible for the "divide by two"-behaviour explained in the question.

Thanks to John Willemse.

Comment: What version of the Framework are(were) you using? Because i could not reproduce the issue, and i've tried both 2.0 and 3.5... (Although i've only tried with just one label inside Panel1, if that has any relevance.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, and was tempted to use the original poster's advice and just divide the desired SplitterDistance by two, as it always seemed to be (nearly but not exactly) twice the width that I asked for.

I tried changing the DockStyle of the children of the two panels to None before setting the SplitterDistance, but in my case it did not have any impact on the problem.

I solved the problem by changing when the SplitterDistance gets set.  Originally I was setting the SplitterDistance on the panel before calling Form.Show().  Setting the SplitterDistance after the form is shown seemed to cure it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want a fixed first panel and a dynamic second one, couldn't you use a TableLayoutPanel instead of a SplitContainer?

Comment: No. The user should be able to resize the panel by hand. But I want to avoid that it automaticly resizes when the form gets maximized, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `DockStyle.None` is a step in the right direction. But it needs 3-6 iterations (shaking the Splitter), until the Panel-Window has the expected dimensions. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out. I needed to have a page open and load the splitter positions from the registry but was very frustrated with the way the watch I set up showed that it kept going back to the design time setting of the control.

To fix it all you do is change the property of "FixedPanel" from "None" to panel1 or panel2. Which is up to you. it only really comes into play when the minimum setting is not small enough and/ or when you have a splitcontainer within another sizable container. the fixed panel stays fixed then. Both panels can be resized as you choose using a mouse though so the word fixed is a little ambiguous in that regard.

so take the design time control. drop it on the form. resize it to fit your requirement and anchor it as necessary. nothing else except making one of the panels fixed. There is a property called "IsSplitterFixed" don't touch it, it's one of the reasons this control becomes unstable and must stay false, the panel.minsize properties should be set at design time based on requirements and you will always have to take cognisance of their values.

live happily ever after!

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I was observing the same thing: `SplitterDistance` works as long as `FixedPanel` is not set but the fix was ensuring `.Size` is set to a value bigger than `.SplitterDistance` *before* setting it:

```cs
splitContainer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 1000); // !!!
splitContainer.FixedPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;
splitContainer.SplitterDistance = 400;
```